# Windows Mobile Application without UI (Service like)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing Windows Mobile Application which will be automatically started in system startup. I need to run this application as service that should not show UI (Progress indication) when it loads and do some processing while loading.

I tried to use http://managedserviceswm.codeplex.com/ but it shows UI (Progress indication) as my application is doing heavy processing on start up. Is there any way to do the processing in background (or NON-UI thread) which will not effect user interaction with device and does not show Progress Indication that something is going on in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wait cursor is shown by the execution engine as it loads and JITs the necessary assemblies to run your application.  There is no way to prevent that form happening. All you can do is attempt to minimize it by keeping the amount of constructor and static initialization to a minimum and build up the objects after the CLR has done all of its loading.

Comment: I have no problem with CLR loading. But, my application iteself does heavy processing which takes about 15-20 seconds and wait cursor is shown during that time. Windows Services does not show wait cursor even if it does heavy processing. How can we hide wait cursor only for application processing?

Comment: Unless the application is calling to set the wait cursor (i.e. Cursor.Current = Cursors.Wait) then I can think of no explanation.  I've never seen the wait cursor appear without being asked except duing CLR loading.

Comment: I am not doint Cursor.Current = Cursors.Wait. Its the heavy processing on application start up that cause the cursor to show wait mode. My question is,  "Windows Services does not show wait cursor even if it does heavy processing in background at system startup". How do I achieve the same?

Comment: And I'm saying that you need to delay the processing so it's not happening right at start up.  Give the CLR time to spin up and clear the wait cursor.  The execution engine is turning it on, and you have zero control over that.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the wait cursor explicitly when you start up?  I'd try with the managed Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default as well as P/Invoking if that fails.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I will try that and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I need to put Sleep for 2-5 seconds when my application start? Also, tell me specifics about P/Invoking (which dll and function to use). Thanks.

Comment: SetCursor is the P/Invoke call.  You'll simply do SetCursor.IntPtr.Zero).  A Sleep may work, though I'd be inclined to move all of the work to a background thread.

Comment: Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default is working exactly like I want. Thanks for great suggestion.